# UIWebView does not detect tap when UIPopoverController is active

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller, tap

I'm presenting a `UIPopoverController` above a `UIWebView`, to present a couple of selection options for the user. However I found that while tapping outside the popover will close the popover as expected, but the tap is **not** detected on the webview. I have to tap again on the same location in the webview (to e.g. trigger the next popover controller).

Is there a way to make the webview detect the popover-closing tap?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [passthroughViews property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009306-CH1-SW8) of UIPopoverController

Example:

```
//if you have these somewhere
//UIPopoverController *popoverController.passthroughViews;
//UIWebView *webView

popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:webView];
```

Comment: seems to work, but I can no longer close the popover by tapping outside. Would I have to catch the touches on the webview and manually close the popover?